# VUE Storefront: Category page shows the item counts as string

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n, vue-storefront

in Category.vue I have the following line of code from the default files from storefront

`{{ $t('{count} items', { count: getCategoryProductsTotal }) }}`
https://github.com/vuestorefront/vsf-default/blob/master/pages/Category.vue#L62

but it renders as "{count} items", not with the actual value of the count var.
however, if I added `{{getCategoryProductsTotal}}` outside the translation statement I get the actual value for the total count.

[image]

Comment: Without a full working example, I can't really see the entire problem, but the string that you're passing to `$t` is just a string of `'{count} items'`. If you want string interpolation inside your string, you need to use the backticks like this: `\`${count} items\``.

Comment: @RobertStefanic it's from the official VUE storefront GitHub repo
https://github.com/vuestorefront/vsf-default/blob/master/pages/Category.vue#L62

Comment: Check out my solution

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to insert the count inside the object like below

```
i18n: new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    messages: {
      en: { hello: 'hi there', count: '{val} items' },
      cn: { hello: '你好',  count: '{val} 项目' }
    }
  })
```

and then in template use it like

```
{{ $t('count', { val: getCategoryProductsTotal }) }}
```

Note:

- getCategoryProductsTotal should be a `computed` property.
- if that's a method then use it like

```
{{ $t('count', { val: getCategoryProductsTotal() }) }}
```

But always prefer computed for these use cases

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the version of VSF you are using so we could reproduce it locally. E.g. I've just created a new project with VSF1.12.3 (the newest stable version) and vsf-default theme (1.12.1) and it works perfectly fine.